# Trying to use boundingRect in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

What is wrong with class `Kwadrat`? I have an error:

> Invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Kwadrat'

```
Kwadrat* kwadrat = new Kwadrat(20);
```

I want a moving square on the screen (when it hit 370 on X or 370 on Y coordinate it comes back to middle).

when Kwadrat is classic `QGraphicsRectItem` I have a bug with (0,0) coordinate.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPixmap>
#include "poruszanie.h"
#include <QRectF>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class Kwadrat : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Kwadrat(int size)
        : QGraphicsItem(NULL) // we could parent, but this may confuse at first
    {
        m_boundingRect = QRectF(0, 0, size, size);
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        return m_boundingRect;
    }

private:
    QRectF m_boundingRect;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene*scena=new QGraphicsScene();

   // Poruszanie*kwadrat=new Poruszanie();
   // kwadrat->setRect(0,0,20,20);
   // kwadrat->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
   // scena->addItem(kwadrat);

    Kwadrat*kwadrat=new Kwadrat(20);
    kwadrat->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
    scena->addItem(kwadrat);

    kwadrat->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    kwadrat->setFocus();

    QGraphicsView *widok=new QGraphicsView(scena);
    widok->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    widok->setMinimumSize(400,400);
    widok->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To write your own graphics item, you first create a subclass of
>   QGraphicsItem, and then start by implementing its two pure virtual
>   public functions: boundingRect(), which returns an estimate of the
>   area painted by the item, and paint(), which implements the actual
>   painting.

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#details

So you need to implement the pure virtual function `paint` to do the painting of your `QGraphicsItem` to get rid of the error, your compiler should have shown that, besides telling you that your class is abstract (because of the missing function implementation).